# Linux denies permission on socket bind using boost asio

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm having a problem binding a socket and I get permision denied when running the program as a user.  this line of code generates an error.

`_acceptor = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(io, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), serverPort));`

the error is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
```

what():  bind: Permission denied

However, if I run as root it works fine.  I've tried disabling apparmor and firewall with

```
sudo service apparmor stop
sudo ufw disable
```

but I still have the problem.  Am I missing something that could deny permision?
I'd really like to figure this out as I don't like running my IDE and an unproven program as root.

I'm running xubuntu 13.10 with all updates installed.

Comment: What is the value of `serverPort` ? The first 1024 port are restricted to the root user only so if `serverPort` < 1024 you should try something > 1024

Comment: try to set another port such as 3000, this port might be restricted to a specific service/protocol

Comment: Bloddy.... GAAH.... That was it.  I assumed the port was correct because it was at the beginning of the function but for some reason one of the 3rd party libs I'm using changed the value to 64.  I got rid of the change and now it works!  That's why I hate using iffy libs. I'll have to write my own soon!

Comment: Ok great, I will add the answer so you ca accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On unix systems, the first 1024 port are restricted to the root user only so if `serverPort` < 1024 you should try something > 1024