# python socket why cant i use every port?

Tags: python, sockets, port, ports

So I've been working on my chat and I finished it(with socket module).
This is my code:

## client

```
import socket
print("Make sure to answer everything correctly or else it won't work\n")
my_ip = input('Your ip: ')
my_port = int(input('A random port number: '))
server_ip = input('Server ip: ')
server_port = int(input('Server port: '))
server = (server_ip, server_port)

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((my_ip, my_port))
    count = 0
    name = input('Name: ')
    while True:
        if count == 0:
            msg = input('--> ')
            if msg.lower() == 'q':
                break
            end_msg = name + ': ' + msg
            s.sendto(end_msg.encode('utf-8'), server)
            count += 1
        elif count == 1:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))
            msg = input('--> ')
            if msg.lower() == 'q':
                break
            end_msg = name + ': ' + msg
            s.sendto(end_msg.encode('utf-8'), server)
        else:
            pass
    s.close()
main()
```

## server

```
import socket
host = input('Host/ip: ')
port = int(input('Port number: '))
users = []
def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    print('[!] Server started\n')
    while True:
        try:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            if addr not in users:
                users.append(addr)
            print('[*] Message from {} | {}'.format(addr, data.decode('utf-8')))
            for user in users:
                s.sendto(data, user)
        except:
            pass
    s.close()
main()
```

As you see I have inputs at the client code and I've tried to use different ports but when I use port 3 or so I get an error 'Persmission denied'. It's no big deal but im interested why this happends, could someone explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20826189/238704) answer to a similar question.

Comment: Only `root` can use ports under 1024

Answer (score 0):

On many systems only root can bind to ports lower than 1024.